# jQuery.validate require_from_group - Error Styling Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-validate

I really don't know how to classify this, if it's a CSS issue or a javascript issue.

When I have multiple groups in my validate init, and then those groups require more than ONE in each group, I first get the proper display - all the fields in the group are set as ERROR.

But when I begin entering in data into one of the fields, two of the fields stay as errors (which they should until ALL the requirements are met), but the rest remove the error status.

**Example:** [JFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/murphy1976/v0ww0xke/3/)

In this example, I have two groups of four fields. The first group requires 3 fields be filled in, the second group requires that 2 fields be filled in.

Am I declaring my validation incorrectly?

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contact-form").validate({
    groups: {
      links: "link_fb link_tw link_yt link_db",
      links2: "link_fb2 link_tw2 link_yt2 link_db2"
    },
    rules: {
      'link_fb': {
        require_from_group: [3, ".link_group"]
      },
      'link_tw': {
        require_from_group: [3, ".link_group"]
      },
      'link_yt': {
        require_from_group: [3, ".link_group"]
      },
      'link_db': {
        require_from_group: [3, ".link_group"]
      },
      'link_fb2': {
        require_from_group: [2, ".link_group2"]
      },
      'link_tw2': {
        require_from_group: [2, ".link_group2"]
      },
      'link_yt2': {
        require_from_group: [2, ".link_group2"]
      },
      'link_db2': {
        require_from_group: [2, ".link_group2"]
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't see that you've done anything wrong.  There's something wonky with how the plugin applies the error class to the input elements in the case of `require_from_group`.  You should report this to the developer on his GitHub page.

Comment: Upon further review... remove your `groups` option entirely and try again.  Something is really messed up in the second grouping... it refuses to validate at all.

Comment: `".link_group2"` should be `".link_group_2"` but this does not solve your original problem.